# $exception is not declared, it may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: vb.net, exception, insert

```
 Public Sub cmdPush_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdPush.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to add this record?", "Adding records", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Try
                Call ConntoDB()
                conn.Open()
                Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand
                cmd2 = New SqlCommand
                cmd2.Connection = conn
                cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO studentaccounts (
                Account_Number,
                Tuition_Fee,
                iTuition_Fee,
                Tuition_Fee_DC,
                Bus_Fee,
                iBus_Fee,
                Bus_Fee_DC,
                Full_Name) VALUES (
                @accountnumber,
                @tuitionfee,
                @ituitionfee,
                @tuitionfeedc,
                @busfee,
                @ibusfee,
                @busfeedc,
                @fullname)"
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountnumber", Me.txtaccount.Text)
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tuitionfee", Me.lbltuitionfee.Text)
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ituitionfee", frmSetupTuitionFee.txttuition.Text)
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tuitionfeedc", frmSetupTuitionFee.txtdiscountrate.Text)
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", Me.lblfullname.Text)
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@busfee", Me.lblbusfee.Text)
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ibusfee", frmSetupBusFee.txtbus.Text)
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@busfeedc", frmSetupBusFee.txtdiscountratebus.Text)
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Data has been added!")
                Loadlastrow()
                conn.Dispose()
                conn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            conn.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
            End Try
        Else
        End If
    End Sub
```

I am so clueless im getting an error of $exception is not declared, it may be inaccessible due to its protection level. What have I missed?
Also this code was still working, i saved the file went for lunch and when I came back this issue is occurred.

Comment: you are limiting your variables scope by putting them in the try catch, try declaring them before.

Comment: $exception does not appear in your listing... is it used anywhere else in your code? Also you don't seem to be disposing/closing you conn correctly. After MsgBox(ex.Message) add Finally then have conn.Close and conn.Dispose.. This will make sure that your connection is closed and disposed properly. Currently the conn is only closed/disposed if an exception occurs.

Comment: the `conn.dispose()` and `conn.Close` should be in the `finally` bit of the `try catch finally`

Comment: I'd recommend to use `Using` with your connection if possible, rather than manually managing the call to `Dispose`.

Comment: Hi guys! I appreciate all the answers! I figured the issue when it is supposed to be "Private Sub cmdPush_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPush.Click" Also, I will use those tips as well for the finally! Thank you again! :D

Comment: Placing dispose() and conn.close on the try statement doesn't work at all?